# Joomla 2.5 template language override not working

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How do I need to specify a language override for my template in order for Joomla! to use it?

It's specific language tags for the COM_STORELOCATOR component.

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.tpl_XXX.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

The file with overrides should be located here:

```
/language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini
```

You can manage the template overrides directly from the Joomla! backend.

Go to Extensions > Language Manager > Overrides

**Option 2**

Check the [solution proposed by "mgirardis" in the Joomla! Forums](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=629&t=639128#p2757196):

> You create the folder: `[TEMPLATE_NAME]/language/overrides`
>
> and put inside it the file containing all the desired overrides:
>   `zz-ZZ.override.ini` where `zz-ZZ` is the language you wish to override.
>
> Then in `templateDetails.xml` you add (inside the tags `<languages>`; I'm
>   putting this tag here only to illustrate the idea):
>
> ```
> <languages>
>     <language tag="overrides">language/overrides/zz-ZZ.override.ini</language>
> </languages>
> ```

Comment: Yes, I understand you can use the Overrides, but how do you apply this for a specific template only?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't override something like that.  I usually add a component-specific prefix to my language files to avoid conflicts.  For instance, the title for you would be:

```
echo JTEXT::_("SL_TITLE");
```

Comment: Thats also what I would prefer as it wouldn´t overwrite the wrong stuff in another content.